# EJB EAR file migration form JBoss 6 to JBoss 7

Tags: java, jboss

I have an EAR(JAR) file that deploys just fine to JBoss AS6 but when deployed to JBoss AS7 if fails to start. the first fail message in the log file is:
    [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-11) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."hornetq-jboss-beans.xml"

The next one is:
[org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."dodsrOracle-ds.xml"

My EAR file is dodsr.ear.  What do I have to change in order for this bean file to get properly deployed to AS7?

Answer (score 1):

You should start by updating the jboss libraries you use to compile your application and verify that your application still compiling with the jboss7 libraries

Next the datasources are not configured with -ds.xml files anymore, you need to declare it in your standalone.xml.

This is not like an update from jboss5 to jboss6, you need to do some changes in your application to get it working. I recomend start reading: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/How+do+I+migrate+my+application+from+AS5+or+AS6+to+AS7

But don't panic because the length of the document. Simply try to solve the problems one by one. The modules and dependency management are very important to understand but in some cases you don't need deal with it to get your application working... Depends of you application.

I need more details of the application to be more precise in the response.

Comment: thanks for your response.  I don't need to worry about the oracle driver, I think, since there is a web application that runs on the same server that connects to the same oracle DB.  Am I right about this?  My app is a desktop app and the EJBs are failing to deploy - I do not have the error message yet and am trying to get it from the sys admin.